# Spring-AMQP and different brokers

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I have a project with Spring-AMQP. It's working correctly. I use `CachingConnectionFactory` and `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, and I have a `CompositeConnectionListener` to detect when the connection is close.

But now I need to detect when the broker is down (I can detect it with `CompositeConnectionListener`) and then establish a new connection to a different broker, on a different server, and restart the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with the new connection.

I've been trying for a while but i do not see the way yet.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can let the RabbitMQ client take care of failing over by providing multiple addresses:

```
addresses="host1:5672,host2:5672"
```

If you want to roll your own you will need a delegating connection factory. You might be able to achieve it with a `SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory`. See [the documentation about routing connection factories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#routing-connection-factory).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gary.

Now I have one `SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory` with two `CachingConnectionFactory` (two diferent brokers). And I detect when the connection is closed with `CompositeConnectionListener` and then I can change to the second `CachingConnectionFactory` (manually,I thought that it will be done automatically). It´s working correctly.

But if I try to start with the first broker down, I get:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

and I don’t know how to catch it and change to the second broker. And the same thing happens if I stop the two brokers.

Thank you again!